# Issuer and Audience in JWT .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

Hi everyone I'm trying to do JWT in .net core api and I have a question while configuring JWT in file startup.cs
Specifically I want to ask "ValidIssuer" and "ValidAudience" to do, what does it mean for JWT?
Somebody can help me please, thanks all.

This is my code :

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(option =>
            {
                option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // what to validate
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,    
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    // set up validate data 
                    ValidIssuer = "smesk.in", 
                    ValidAudience = "reader", 
                    IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey

                };



            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically used to whom you want to allow your requests. You can refer this document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validaudience?view=azure-dotnet

And you can set it like this.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {

            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"]

        };
    });
```

**Appsettings.json**

```
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "test.com",
    "Audience": "abc.com"
  }
```

Comment: hmm so ValidIssuer and ValidAudience have the same value right ?? I thought those two were different ??

Comment: they are different. I just gave you example

Comment: Ok thanks for answering me..  can I ask one question more. Is the JWT authentication I am doing that authenticating with firebase??

Comment: sorry, I have no idea of firebase :)

Comment: Does .net check whether the jwt issuer is same as the servername? And who checks the audience?